# Algorithm confirmation

Tags: discussion, scope

I have an algorithm in textual form(in English) from a research paper that deals with meteorology/climatology . If I convert the textual algorithm into pseudo code can I ask it as a question here for confirmation or does it belong to Computational Science Stack Exchange ? The data structures that will support the algorithm are irrelevant as far the question is concerned.

Comment: In addition to pseudo code, another way to represent an algorithm is via a flowchart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We never ended up discussing it really but the [last time we mentioned it](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/a/78/87) people seemed ok with it. I would certainly think that it would be on-topic as long as the question stops at the algorithm, i. e. off-topic if the question is about dealing with errors in the code but on-topic if trying to figure out the validity of an algorithm.

Comment: there will not be any "code" specific to a programming language in my question. It will be "psuedocode" i.e. language agnostic. The algorithm in the research paper is mostly English with some explanation. I want to convert it to suitable code but  I have to verify if my algorithm is  correct or not.

Comment: Then I see no problem with you asking the question